# Oracle sql loader date format issue

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm new to sql loader, and i'm having a problem with the date format.

Here is the input file record sample:

Y,1525039510,http-192.168.2.2,15-01-2011 00:00:032:728,64
Y,1525131958,http-192.168.2.2,15-01-2011 00:00:033:613,75

I'm having a problem with the fourth column, the date.

My current field entry is this:

`start_time DATE "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI`

How do i parse the last part of the input 032:728 (seconds and milliseconds)

I tried SSS:FF3 and SS.FF3, no luck.

Comment: Are you sure you want to load the data into a DATE column rather than a TIMESTAMP?  A TIMESTAMP can store milliseconds, a DATE cannot.  Assuming you want to just get rid of the milliseconds, why are there three numbers for seconds?  Can you really have more than 59 seconds in that portion of the field?

Comment: @Justin Cave: Why are there 3 numbers for seconds? i wish i knew, ask the guy who gave me the input file!

Comment: @ d-live: nope, date format not recognized

Comment: Can you have more than 59 seconds in the "seconds" field?  Or is the first number always going to be 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could treat the input as a string and transform it with a function. Something like this should work:

```
start_time CHAR to_date(substr(:start_time, 1, 20), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi":0"ss')
```

I had to drop the millisecond part since they are not part of the DATE datatype (`to_date` doesn't recognize the `FF` format).

Answer (score 2):

You can read this into a timestamp field. The data looks a bit weird: 15-01-2011 00:00:033:613,75 but the conversion format should be dd-mm-yyyy hh[24]:mi:0ss:fff,ff
Make sure that your nls settings are as expected.

Ronald.